# C# The type 'ForeignKeyAttribute' exists in both EntityFramework and System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, .net-framework-version

I upgraded project from .net 4.0 to .net 4.5.1.

and I upgraded EntityFramework from 4.3.1 to 6.1.3.

But EntityFramework based on .net 4.0 (\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net40\EntityFramework) because another depended project running .net 4.0.

When I build, I got this error:

The type 'ForeignKeyAttribute' exists in both 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' and 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'd probably need to remove `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;` from your code.

Comment: Hi Ivan. I tried that but I got this error:The type or namespace name 'KeyAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Sorry, disregard my previous comment. Actually in my EF6.1.3 test project I have `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations; using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;` And both attributes are coming from `Assembly System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35`  Looks like something is wrong with `EntityFramework` assembly in your scenario, have no idea how it can be resolved. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for advice. But I upgraded depended projects :)

Answer (score 8):

It may not be enough to simply remove the `DataAnnotations 4.0.0` references from the project. Even though the references to Entity Framework in your packages.config may be updated with the correct version the targetFramework value may still influence how the code gets compiled.

I was upgrading an ASP.NET MVC 3 application that was originally targeting Framework 4.0. I first upgraded the NuGet packages, which included EntityFramework 4.x. Later I learned I needed a newer .NET Framework version. After choosing to upgrade each project to .NET Framework 4.7.1, I started running into [CS0433](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0433) errors. Upgrading the Framework version *after* upgrading the NuGet packages appears to leave the targetFramework unchanged.

To solve this problem, I manually updated each project's packages.config file with new targetFramework values from `net40` to `net471`. To make these updated values take effect, from the NuGet Package Manager Console I ran `Update-Package -reinstall`. Now the `DataAnnotations` included in 'EntityFramework 6.2.0' are used instead of the externally-available ones in 4.0.0.

Comment: Update-Package -reinstall worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework 6 includes a lot of stuff from the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations and System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema namespaces.
As far as I can see, the fix is to remove the projects **Reference** to System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

Comment: I tried this but if I remove the reference of the DLL `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`, i get the error `KeyAttribute` class not found because is not in EntityFramework assembly. Any ideas of how to solve this?

Comment: @EinerSantana That's a good question.  Let me check.  EF uses [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=true, IsNullable=false)] to indicate the primary key.  Huh.  EF 6.2 I see only "IndexAttribute",none of the others.  Have they changed things on me again?